# Debugging ReactJS in Webstorm - Object no longer null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm

I am not sure how I can find out why this is not working. My state `user.data` is `null` in app.js (`user.data === null = true`), however in auth.js `user.data === null` is `false`. I am not sure why and there is no place to put any kind of alert or debugger in auth.js to show me the value of user.data?

Firefox's React debugging tools shows me that it is evaluates to `false` (`user.data === null = false`) however it won't show me what `user.data` actually is. I am wondering if it is being converted into some kind of object rather than null?

[image]

Using WebStorm 2017.2 and react-boilerplate v3.5.0

#### app.js

```
/**
 *
 * App
 *
 * This component is the skeleton around the actual pages, and should only
 * contain code that should be seen on all pages. (e.g. navigation bar)
 */

import React from 'react';
import { Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logout } from '../../actions/user';

import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { makeSelectUser } from './selectors';

import { userIsAuthenticatedRedir, userIsNotAuthenticatedRedir, userIsAdminRedir,
    userIsAuthenticated, userIsNotAuthenticated } from '../../auth'

import LoginComponent from '../../components/Login';
import Home from '../../components/Home';
import ProtectedComponent from '../../components/Protected';

const getUserName = (user) => {
  if (user.data === null) {
      return ('userIsNotAuthenticatedDefaults: user.data === null') //This is true
  } 
};

const Login = userIsNotAuthenticatedRedir(LoginComponent);
const Protected = userIsAuthenticatedRedir(ProtectedComponent);


const UserName = ({ user }) => (<div>{getUserName(user)}</div>);

const LoginLink = userIsNotAuthenticated(() => <h>UserIsNotAuth (Login) Link</h> /*<NavLink to="/login">Login</NavLink>*/);
const LogoutLink = userIsAuthenticated(({ logout }) => <h>UserIsAuth (Logout) Link </h> /*<a href="#" onClick={() => logout()}>Logout</a>*/);

function App({ user, logout }) {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(user));
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test App</h1>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink>
            <h1>This is the app component</h1>
           <NavLink exact to="/protected">Protected</NavLink>
          <NavLink exact to="/admin">Admin</NavLink>
        </nav>
        <nav>
         <LoginLink />
          <LogoutLink logout={logout} />
         <UserName user={user} />
        </nav>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/protected" component={Protected} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


const mapStateToProps = createSelector(
    makeSelectUser(),
    (user) => ({user})
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(App);
```

#### auth.js

```
import locationHelperBuilder from 'redux-auth-wrapper/history4/locationHelper';
import { connectedRouterRedirect } from 'redux-auth-wrapper/history4/redirect';
import connectedAuthWrapper from 'redux-auth-wrapper/connectedAuthWrapper';

import Loading from './components/Loading';

const locationHelper = locationHelperBuilder({});

const userIsAuthenticatedDefaults = {
  authenticatedSelector: (user) => user.data !== null,
  authenticatingSelector: (user) => user.isLoading,
  wrapperDisplayName: 'UserIsAuthenticated',
};

export const userIsAuthenticated = connectedAuthWrapper(userIsAuthenticatedDefaults);

export const userIsAuthenticatedRedir = connectedRouterRedirect({
  ...userIsAuthenticatedDefaults,
  AuthenticatingComponent: Loading,
  redirectPath: '/login',
});

export const userIsAdminRedir = connectedRouterRedirect({
  redirectPath: '/',
  allowRedirectBack: false,
  authenticatedSelector: (user) => user.data !== null && user.data.isAdmin,
  predicate: (user) => user.isAdmin,
  wrapperDisplayName: 'UserIsAdmin',
});

const userIsNotAuthenticatedDefaults = {
  // Want to redirect the user when they are done loading and authenticated
  authenticatedSelector: (user) => user.data === null, // This is somwhow now false
  wrapperDisplayName: 'UserIsNotAuthenticated',
};

export const userIsNotAuthenticated = connectedAuthWrapper(userIsNotAuthenticatedDefaults);

export const userIsNotAuthenticatedRedir = connectedRouterRedirect({
  ...userIsNotAuthenticatedDefaults,
  redirectPath: (user, ownProps) => locationHelper.getRedirectQueryParam(ownProps) || '/protected',
  allowRedirectBack: false,
});
```

#### selectors.js:

```
/**
 * The global state selectors
 */

import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const selectRoute = (state) => state.get('route');

const selectUser = (state) => state.get('user');

const makeSelectLocation = () => createSelector(
  selectRoute,
  (routeState) => routeState.get('location').toJS(),
);

const makeSelectUser = () => createSelector(
    selectUser, (userState) => userState.toJS(),
);


export {
    makeSelectLocation,
    makeSelectUser,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out I needed to be doing:

```
state => state.toJS().user.data === null
```

for this to work.

Putting alert() in authenticatedSelector: (user) => alert(user.data) worked which I did not expect - I would have thought it would require a Boolean value?